# How to create JQuery-UI widgets dynamically

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I understand that I can use `.on` to bind functions to DOM elements when some event occurs on an element.

I have been using JQuery-ui, and I want to create different JQuery-ui elements once they have loaded on the page. For example, create a button when one is loaded on the page:

```
$(document.body).on('load', '.my-button', function(){
    $(this).button()
});
```

However, this doesn't work (in fact, the handler is never reached).

How can I create JQuery-ui widgets when they load in the DOM?

Comment: You can't. Instead, initialize them when they are added. `$("<button>mybutton</button>").appendTo("body").button();`

Comment: You `load` event in never firing because "The load event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have been completely loaded. This event can be sent to any element associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the window object.". Your button is none of those. When do you want the event happen exactly?

Comment: I use `button` as an example, but it could just as easily be `autocomplete` or `accordion`. Is there no way to initialize them using `.on`?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery does not fire any events when an element is created. Instead, use [the watch plugin](http://darcyclarke.me/dev/watch/) and run your `button()`s from there.